# ObjectAnimator retaining animated View

Tags: android, android-animation

I am doing translate animation using object animator. After successful translation I was trying to retain the location of animation using setting up new layoutparams. But on animation end when I set existing layoutparams without changing any margin view retains its location and working perfectly.

```
    private void IndicatorAnimation(View currentView){

    final FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.indicator);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) fl.getLayoutParams();

    final int[] origin = new int[2];
    fl.getLocationInWindow(origin);

    final int[] destination = new int[2];

    currentView.getLocationInWindow(destination);

    ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fl, "translationX", origin[0], destination[0]);
    oa.setDuration(300);
    oa.start();

    oa.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) fl.getLayoutParams();
             fl.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

My Question is how it is possible? Because getLayoutparams at animation end gives me same parameters which were there before animation starts.

Answer (score 0):

There are actual properties that belong to the `[View.TransformationInfo][1]` class which include `mTranslationX` and `mTranslationY`. This is basically how the View keeps track of this information, not by updating the LayoutParams.

The TransformationInfo class is not publicly available, but (on API 14) you are able to use the View's properties of X, Y, etc. to get this information. `onAnimationEnd` you could reset those values and set the LayoutParams margins to accommodate (this of course depends on your layout how to be accomplish this).

Comment: AFAIK ObjectAnimator does not have setFillAfter method. How can I check this TransformationInfo which I don't see in View object. I am API level 11.

Comment: The Property class requires API 14, so you'll need to use the support library or something similar. I misremembered the ObjectAnimator class, it doesn't have a setFillAfter method but you could accomplish the same thing by immediately updating the X and Y to their previous values onAnimationEnd.

Comment: If I remove setLayoutParams from animationend block View does not hold at the end. Which means it is doing something which I not aware of.

Comment: Then perhaps I'm confused with what you are asking. Animators do not update the LayoutParams of a View, they update the given property within TransformationInfo property (so `translationX` corresponds to the property `mTranslationX`). This occurs within a loop, and `onAnimationEnd` LayoutParams will remain untouched, but `mTranslationX` will equal `destination[0]`. The only point worth noting as I see it is that `setLayoutParams` will force a re-layout regardless whether the parameters have changed.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I was talking about and hence my initial question was how come setLayoutParams comes here in the picture and does the job. In fact, I have traced all layoutparams data before animation start and at end they are exactly same then how come setLayoutParams force View to retain its position.

Comment: The `setLayoutParams` accomplishes this because it calls `requestLayout`. Unless something else in your code/ layout is acting on this View, the only other thing that stands out to me is that you are updating `translationX` with `origin[0]`. `translationX` "controls where the View is located as a delta from its left and top coordinates which are set by its layout container." You should use either `x` or supply 0f for the starting value and `destination[0] - origin[0]` as your final value.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will investigate it further and let you know.